# Fragments and screen orienatation issues

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, screen-orientation, android-fragmentactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
FragmentTransaction ft;
Button b1, b2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, new Fragment1());

    } else {

        ft.add(R.id.LinearLayout1, new MainFragment());
        ft.add(R.id.LinearLayout2, new Fragment1());

    }

    ft.commit();

 }

}

public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{
 Button b1,b2;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_fragment, container, false);
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // ---Button view---
    b1 = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.f1);
    b2 = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.f2);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);


}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v==b1){
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.LinearLayout2,new Fragment2());
        ft.commit();


    }
    if(v==b2){
        FragmentManager fm =getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.LinearLayout2,new Fragment3());
        ft.commit();


    }
}

}
```

The problem here when the application is running in portrait mode the Fragment1 appear as i want   and when i change the orientation to landscape ,the MainFragment and Fragment2 appear as i want too but Fragment1 still there,
and when i change orientation again to portrait ,the application stopped.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is you are assuming that every time onCreate is called you are starting out with no fragments...which is not the case.

The first time onCreate is called for MainActivity there will be no fragments. Assuming the device was in portrait, Fragment1 will be added. When you rotate to landscape then another instance of Fragment1 will be added and an instance of MainFragment. You now have three fragment instances. When you go back to portrait its going to want to add ANOTHER instance of Fragment1...but it is probably crashing because the portrait layout doesn't have R.id.LinearLayout1 or R.id.LinearLayout2.

Bottom line is...you need to remove fragments once you are done with them...they don't just go away by themselves.

Comment: Thank you @user1132647, I think i resolved it by calling popBackStackImmediate() method from onPause()